# How to create an adjacency matrix in R most efficiently?

Tags: r, matrix, igraph

I have data that follows a similar format to

[image: Name,Fruit].

The goal is to create an adjacency matrix that demonstrates the relationships between the different names. If two names are related, 1 is inputed into the corresponding cell in the adjacency matrix. If
not, 0 is inputed. Two names are related if both names have the same fruit. For instance, since Jake has Apple and Carly has Apple, they are both related. Here is a sample adjacency matrix based on the sample data provided.

[image: Name x Name].

What is the most efficient method of doing this in R programming when I have over 600,000 rows of data? Any suggestions?

Comment: How many names N and fruit F do you have? What is your current code and its runtime? Why is runtime an issue? I presume for efficiency you treat names and fruits as categorical, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code with `igraph`

```
library(igraph)
get.adjacency(graph_from_data_frame(df,directed = FALSE),sparse = FALSE)
```

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding how we can modify this code and use it for a data frame with more than one column and see the relation between all the columns?